# How to uninstall program that is not listed in the uninstaller

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I really love this video converter called [Total Video Converter](http://www.effectmatrix.com/total-video-converter/). But there's one thing that it annoys me about it. The video player which is installed along with it. The installer doesn't even allow you to customize the installation. The video converter is installed along with the video player. If you search for the total video player in the uninstaller, nothing is there except for total video converter.

What do I do? Can I go into the registry and delete something there so that I can rid of this video player installed along with total video converter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if this answers your question but have a look at [Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/). If this does what you require as well then you can just totally [pun intended!] remove Total Video Convertor and the annoyance you have with it.

I have never used the product but for others you may wish to say why the video part annoys you. If its the default player then you can just do the following:

1. Right click on media file (if on XP you may need to use the shift key)
2. Choose Open With
3. Select the application and tick make default

If this steps are unclear try these URLS:

1. [For Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320036)
2. [For Vista/7](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6172036.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)

Is a tool that can help you uninstall something that does not provide an uninstaller. There is a freeware version you can use.